# PHP : How to include another array's elements in another array's index?

Tags: php, arrays

I have two arrays:

```
array(3)
{  
   [0]=>
      string(1) "1"
   [1]=>
      string(1) "1"
   [2]=>
      string(1) "2"
}

array(3)
{  
   [0]=>
      string(1) "abc"
   [1]=>
      string(1) "def"
   [2]=>
      string(1) "ghi"
}
```

Is there any way I could put the first array's elements into the second array's index producing the following result :

```
array(3)
{  
   [1]=>
      string(1) "abc"
   [1]=>
      string(1) "def"
   [2]=>
      string(1) "ghi"
}
```

How can I do this in PHP? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Array cannot contain same(duplicate) keys

Comment: The function you are looking for is `array_combine($keys, $values)` but as stated, it won't work with this example

Comment: Okay, i'll try to use mutlidimensional arrays

Comment: What are you really trying to do? What is the purpose? Can you give us a more realistic example? Maybe you are just trying to fix something from the wrong end?

Comment: @Andreas I want to make a question-answer system like stackoverflow, where one question can have multiple answers. I wanted to display all the answers from each paticular question, and to do that I needed to differentiate the answer array elements by adding the question id. Do you have any ideas?

Comment: So in this case array1 is the question id. And array2 is answer/question/comment?  And you want to combine them somehow?

Comment: @Andreas Yes, thats right

Comment: Ok what about this? It will not be like your array, and we know that won't work anyways. But this has the id as key and questions in answers in subarray below it. See if it can fit your needs https://3v4l.org/qpJDA

Comment: @Andreas Yep, thats what I was looking for. Thank you

Comment: Posted it as an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the expected output is impossible the next best thing it to make a multidimensional array where the question id is a subarray for answers.

```
$arr1 = [1,1,2];
$arr2 = ["abc","def","ghi"];

Foreach($arr1 as $key => $id){
    $threads[$id][] = $arr2[$key];
}

Var_dump($threads)
```

Outputs:

```
array(2) {
  [1]=>
     array(2) {
       [0]=> "abc"
       [1]=> "def"
     }
  [2]=>
     array(1) {
       [0]=> "ghi"
     }
}
```

https://3v4l.org/qpJDA

Answer (score 0):

You can use "array_combine" method for this purpose.
http://php.net/array-combine

However, you cannot have same multiple indexes in an array

```
array(3)
{  
   [1]=> "abc"
   [1]=> "def"
   [2]=> "ghi"
}
```

You have index "1" twice in array. So "def" will replace "abc" in your array

Comment: I mistakenly submitted it

Comment: So should I make multidimensional arrays?

Comment: Then how do you suggest I go on with this issue?

Comment: I think you already have this array in good shape. you can use it right as it is now. however if you really need to produce that result array, you can `array_combine` function but you need to make sure values are unique in first array.